# Android OS and postgreSQL

Tags: android, postgresql

We are undertaking an Android project but need to connect to postgreSQL server which we use throughout our other projects.
Any suggestions on a starting point for this?
Is there anything out there (paid or unpaid) that will allow us to achieve this?

I realize that this is a pretty general question, and although we have extensive experience with writing desktop client/server apps, we have little experience with programming for mobile devices.

Answer (score 7):

I would write a RestFUL API or WebService to be used as front end for your Android device to connect to your PostgreSQL backend.

I don't think you will be able to connect directly your Android App to a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with a lightweight REST interface that would talk to PostgreSQL in the backend. Have a look at [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by implementing an intermediary web service. The Android application would send requests to the web service, which would serve as a gatekeeper to isolate the PostgreSQL server from the internet at large.