# Can't connect Android to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: android, postgresql

This is my first post on stackoverflow so hopefully I don't sound too incompetent.  I'm having an issue connecting my Android App to a PostgresDB that I created.  I used the code from this tutorial http://appliedcoffeetechnology.tumblr.com/post/10657124340.  Although I modified the String url ... line to the following:
`String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.101:5556/postgres?user=postgres&password=yeahright";`
I followed the other instructions on downloading the JDBC and adding it to the package, I also added the internet permissions line.

I've configured the postgreSQL DB on my Windows 7 machine to allow connections, and even set the incoming connections to "trust" so that the password won't get in the way.  I also opened up the 5556 port on the Windows firewall.  I can connect to it from my Ubuntu laptop, using the following command: `psql 192.168.1.101 -U postgres -p 5556 -d postgres` 
However, when running the Android App (on a real device) I get "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" thrown by the `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)` call.

Thank you greatly in advance for your help, and let me know if I can provide any other useful information.

Craig Ringer below mentioned a web service app. Originally I was hesitant as I didn't want to add an even steeper incline to my learning curve, but I decided to go with Django, and it has been amazingly simple.

Comment: Android version? Target device(s)?

Comment: Running Ice-Cream-Sandwich on a Galaxy S Tab2 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Android doesn't support JDBC natively. (Update: newer versions do). Honestly, you're *WAY* better off running a web service and having your Android app communicate with the DB via web service requests.

Search SO for "android postgresql".

Some related discussions:

- [Android OS and postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331014/android-os-and-postgresql)
- [How to create webservice in java using apache tomcat using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634167/how-to-create-webservice-in-java-using-apache-tomcat-using-postgresql)
- [Driver JDBC PostgreSQL with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435609/driver-jdbc-postgresql-with-android)
- [How can I securely (indirectly) query a postgresql database within android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881538/how-can-i-securely-indirectly-query-a-postgresql-database-within-android)
- [PostgreSQL JDBC connection fails on Android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970918/postgresql-jdbc-connection-fails-on-android-4-0)

Comment: I'm kinda crunched for time, is there any way that you know of where I can get something simple up and running?  It's been a long time since I set up a webservice, and the DB host is a Windows machine, which usually means there are very few resources on configuring it.  For right now there will be two Android devices using the DB and queries/modifications will be fairly far apart.

If the webservice is the only way to go, I understand.

Comment: Looking at one of the posts you listed above (How to create webservice in java using apache tomcat using PostgreSQL) you mentioned JBoss AS 7, Jersey, and RESTEasy.  I assume that if I go with JBoss AS 7 then I don't need to look into Jersey or RESTEasy.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Lokist Lots of people hack stuff together with PHP etc. Pick an already-familiar language and build something with it using a REST service library for that language. I find JAX-RS on Java application servers easy; you might prefer something else. A search for "REST" and your language of choice might be informative.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get indicates that you did not copy the postgres jdbc driver jar into your application.

Having said that, direct SQL connections to a remote database perhaps even going over a 3g network may not give the performance that you desire.

If you just need a database in your application to store some stuff you should look at the embedded SQLite database.

Comment: The .jar file ends up inside the "Referenced Libraries" section.  Is there something else I should look at to determine whether or not the jar is making it into the package?

I'm actually storing the DB on a remote windows server so that multiple Android devices can access it at once.  That being said, performance really shouldn't be an issue, maybe a max of 10 queries in a second.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this will be over WiFi only.